# click event being removed on previous elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

**answer:**

```
/* I bound the events via the parent instead of binding it 
   on each span tag individually. this allowed me to manipulate
   the span tags uniquely. ( thank you Jason P ) */
$( '.selected-option-wrapper' ).on( 'click', 'span', function() { });
```

---

**disclaimer:**

I am losing my mind.

**details:**

I am trying to list in `html` a bunch a options that a user selected via a `ul/li` dropdown. I want the user to click on a `li a` and have part of the html within the a tag, placed in a separate `div`.

For example:

**html**

```
// html within the li tag that I want cloned over
<a id="met" class="item-1" href="#">
    <div class="left check-wrapper">
        <span class="gicon-ok"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="hide item-display"> // exact element to be moved over
        <span class="gicon-remove-sign left remove-option-item"></span>
    <div class="left">Metallic Thread</div>
</a>
```

**javascript**

```
$( '.options' ).find( 'a' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {

    ind_option_html = $( this ).find( '.item-display' ).clone();

    /* attach a click event to the span tag */
    ind_option_html.find( 'span' ).on( 'click', function() { 
        console.log( this );
    });

    /* this is in a $.each loop that appends each new ind_option_html */
    $( '.selected-option-wrapper' ).show().append( ind_option_html );

});
```

**problem**

whenever I click just one `li a` the function fires fine, the `this` for the `span` tag is logged out. but what is amazing is that when a user clicks another `li a` the `click` event is placed on ONLY the most recent `span` tag.

Where is the `onclick` event going with the first `span` tag?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you may be able to avoid the problem using event delegation so you don't have to rebind events every time an element is clicked.

Comment: could you link me to a resource that explains what you're referring to in more depth?

Comment: [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). See the part about direct and delegated events. Basically, you would bind the event handler to `.selected-option-wrapper` instead of to each option. `$('.selected-option-wrapper').on('click', 'span', function() { ... });` And you would only need to define that on DOM ready, not every time something is clicked.

Comment: Dude, Jason P, put that as an answer, it was correct!! :) thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're having the problem you are, but you can probably avoid it using event delegation. Instead of binding the event handler each time, do it like this when the DOM is ready:

```
$('.selected-option-wrapper').on('click', 'span', function() { ... });
```

See [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and the section about direct and delegated events.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the initial `var ind_option_html` (or is it an accidental global)? Looks like all of the instances of the click handler use the same reference, which is always the last one to be processed.

So your fix would be:

```
ind_option_html = $( this ).find( '.item-display' ).clone();
```

to:

```
var ind_option_html = $( this ).find( '.item-display' ).clone();
```

Comment: it is initiated at the top of the function. they are referring to the same variable name, but the contents are being erased with each new `span`; tried your code, doesn't work :/

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. It's not being referenced in any callbacks once you've made the clone.